# java swing GUI error on windows

Tags: java, swing

I have a java swing application which I've developed in fedora 14, application is working properly on fedora 14 without any problem. But when I tried it on windows 7 it is not working properly ex. menu bar shows parent menu items but menus are not shown when clicking them parent menu items, tabbed panes are shown in black. and systems seems like freeze. I try this in widows xp and got the same result with graphics. please tell me what could be the error in my application.

here is the code for starting point,

```
public class SplashScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {    
    String filePath = File.separator;
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SplashScreen.class);
    /** Creates new form SplashScreen */
    public SplashScreen() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(400, 250);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        try {
            initSetup();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initSetup() throws Exception {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Connection con = null;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    con = JDBCConnectionPool.getInstance().checkOut();

                    if (con == null) {
                        lblMessage.setText("No database connection found!");
                        logger.debug("No database connection found!");
                    } else {
                        lblMessage.setText("Loading the system...");
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                    logger.debug(ex.getMessage());
                } finally {

                    if (con != null) {

                        try {
                            PropertyConfigurator.configure(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("conf/log4j.properties"));
                            logger.info("Starting the system!");                            


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                        new Login().setVisible(true);
                        dispose();
                        JDBCConnectionPool.getInstance().checkIn(con);
                        return;
                    }
                    lblMessage.setText("Error occured... exiting the system");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        System.exit(0);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

login screen

```
/** Creates new form Login */
    public Login() {

        userAuth = new UserAuthentication();
        initComponents();        
        add(pnlControlls);        
        addButtonListeners();
        addTextFieldListeners();
        setSize(400, 250);
        setTitle("Loging");
        //pack();

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


private void login() {        
        txtAlert.setText("");
        UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
        char[] p = txtPassword.getPassword();

        String pw = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            pw = pw + p[i];
        }

        user.setUsername(txtUsername.getText());
        user.setPassword(StringHasher.getInstance().getHash(pw));
        UserDTO authUser = userAuth.authenticate(user);

        if (authUser == null) {
            txtAlert.setText("<html>Internal error...</html>");
        } else {

            if (authUser.getIsActive() && authUser.isIsAvailable()) {
                Main main = Main.getInstance();
                CurrentUser.getInstance().setUserName(authUser.getUsername());
                Main.getInstance().setUserName(authUser.getUsername());
                Main.getInstance().setFullNameOnUserName(authUser.getFullName());
                Main.getInstance().prepareMenu();
                Main.getInstance().setVersion(System.getProperty("version"));
                main.setVisible(true);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(main);
                this.dispose();

//here Main is the main user gui interface which user interacts with
            } else if (!authUser.getIsActive() && authUser.isIsAvailable()) {
                txtAlert.setText("<html>User account is inactive!</html>");
            } else {
                txtAlert.setText("<html>Username or password is incorrect, <br> please check again.</html>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Sometimes I get drop down menus when I minimize and maximize the application but menus are overlapped as bellow,

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code so that we can help you.

Comment: For better help sooner, please include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You're accessing Swing components from other threads than the event dispatch thread. Start by avoiding this. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: What video cards are in the windows boxes? There is a known big with ati video cards

Comment: You missing the UI construction code, makes testing it a real pain